# Xdebug 3 not showing in phpinfo on m1 Monterey

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, apple-m1

After installing xdebug with `sudo pecl install xdebug` it looks that is installed but only in CLI.

`php -i | grep "xdebug"` - this returns a lot of rows

Then when I go in my browser, in `phpinfo()` is nothing relate to xdebug. I've checked that I run the same php instance, both CLI and Apache are using `/opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/php.ini` ini file, I've made changes and they were visible in both CLI and Web. Also

If I try a function it returns fatal error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function xdebug_info()`

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post year and a half late while trying to solve the same issue. I work on the Monterey with intel chipset.

I presume that the docs were changed from the time you posted but the command you are using is for intel chipset. You can see it [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/install#pecl).

Current doc state.

Intel chipset:

```
pecl install xdebug
```

m1 chips(and fish :P)

```
arch -arm64 sudo pecl install xdebug
```

or

```
arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Off to solving my own old problems wish me luck and hope I helped somebody